# yii2: trouble with using shopping cart extension

Tags: yii2, shopping-cart, yii-extensions

I trying to use https://github.com/omnilight/yii2-shopping-cart

I change my product model like this

```
class ShopItems extends ActiveRecord implements CartPositionInterface
{
    use CartPositionTrait;

    //...

    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->price;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    //...
}
```

I added action in my controller

```
public function actionAddToCart($id)
{
    $cart = new ShoppingCart();

    $model = ShopItems::findOne($id);
    if ($model) {
        $cart->put($model, 1);
        return $this->redirect(['cart-view']);
    }
    throw new NotFoundHttpException();
}
```

And of course add component in main config.

```
'components' => [
    'cart' => [
        'class' => 'yz\shoppingcart\ShoppingCart',
        'cartId' => 'my_application_cart',
    ]
]
```

How can i add product in cart now?
I find [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/60551-shopping-cart/), but i can't understand how build action form.

Please, help!

**UPD**

I use action like this:

```
  public function actionAddToCart($id) {
    $cart = new ShoppingCart();
    $model = ShopItems::findOne($id);
    if ($model) {
      $cart->put($model, 1);
      return print_r($cart);
//      return $this->redirect(['cart-view']);
    }
    throw new NotFoundHttpException();
  }
```

And get next:

```
yz\shoppingcart\ShoppingCart Object ( [storeInSession] => 1 [session] => yii\web\Session Object ( [flashParam] => __flash [handler] => [_cookieParams:yii\web\Session:private] => Array ( [httponly] => 1 ) [_hasSessionId:yii\web\Session:private] => [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array ( ) [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => ) [cartId] => yz\shoppingcart\ShoppingCart [_positions:protected] => Array ( [95] => common\modules\shop\models\ShopItems Object ( [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array ( [id] => 95 [category_id] => 1 [title] => Item1 [desc] =>
description

[price] => 200 [currency] => USD [discount] => 20 [in_stock] => 1 [photos] => ["/common/modules/shop/uploads/bfd71_586_0af4a4fdbb56412bcc2b9ac3f9a2432d.jpg","/common/modules/shop/uploads/CkS1pXE8e6g.jpg","/common/modules/shop/uploads/e3pucV_1KJ0.jpg","/common/modules/shop/uploads/eEh-VNPe1jI.jpg","/common/modules/shop/uploads/HbzbFG9kG5s.jpg"] [options] => 0 [created_at] => 1424858174 [updated_at] => 1425898766 ) [_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array ( [id] => 95 [category_id] => 1 [title] => Item1 [desc] =>
description

[price] => 200 [currency] => USD [discount] => 20 [in_stock] => 1 [photos] => ["/common/modules/shop/uploads/bfd71_586_0af4a4fdbb56412bcc2b9ac3f9a2432d.jpg","/common/modules/shop/uploads/CkS1pXE8e6g.jpg","/common/modules/shop/uploads/e3pucV_1KJ0.jpg","/common/modules/shop/uploads/eEh-VNPe1jI.jpg","/common/modules/shop/uploads/HbzbFG9kG5s.jpg"] [options] => 0 [created_at] => 1424858174 [updated_at] => 1425898766 ) [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array ( ) [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array ( [beforeInsert] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior Object ( [createdAtAttribute] => created_at [updatedAtAttribute] => updated_at [value] => [attributes] => Array ( [beforeInsert] => Array ( [0] => created_at [1] => updated_at ) [beforeUpdate] => updated_at ) [owner] => common\modules\shop\models\ShopItems Object *RECURSION* ) [1] => evaluateAttributes ) [1] => ) ) [beforeUpdate] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior Object ( [createdAtAttribute] => created_at [updatedAtAttribute] => updated_at [value] => [attributes] => Array ( [beforeInsert] => Array ( [0] => created_at [1] => updated_at ) [beforeUpdate] => updated_at ) [owner] => common\modules\shop\models\ShopItems Object *RECURSION* ) [1] => evaluateAttributes ) [1] => ) ) ) [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array ( [0] => yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior Object ( [createdAtAttribute] => created_at [updatedAtAttribute] => updated_at [value] => [attributes] => Array ( [beforeInsert] => Array ( [0] => created_at [1] => updated_at ) [beforeUpdate] => updated_at ) [owner] => common\modules\shop\models\ShopItems Object *RECURSION* ) ) [_quantity:protected] => 8 ) ) [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array ( ) [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array ( ) ) 1
```

And after it `<?php print_r( Yii::$app->cart ) ?>` in cart-view show this:

```
yz\shoppingcart\ShoppingCart Object ( [storeInSession] => 1 [session] => yii\web\Session Object ( [flashParam] => __flash [handler] => [_cookieParams:yii\web\Session:private] => Array ( [httponly] => 1 ) [_hasSessionId:yii\web\Session:private] => [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array ( ) [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => ) [cartId] => my_application_cart [_positions:protected] => Array ( ) [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array ( ) [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your product view:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['class'=>'form-horizontal', 'action'=>Url::toRoute(['controllername/add-to-cart','id'=>$product->id])]); ?>

    <?=Html::input('submit','submit','Add to cart',[
                'class'=>'button add',

              ])?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

And in your controller:

```
public function actionAddToCart($id)
{
    $cart = Yii::$app->cart;;

    $model = ShopItems::findOne($id);
    if ($model) {
        $cart->put($model, 1);
        return $this->redirect(['cart-view']);
    }
    throw new NotFoundHttpException();
}
```

Cart index view:

```
<?php

        /** @var ShoppingCart $sc */
        foreach(Yii::$app->cart->positions as $position){
          echo $this->render('_cart_item',['position'=>$position]);
          //var_dump($position);
        }


      ?>
```

in _cart_item view $position is ShopItems model:

```
<?= $position->id ?>
<?= $position->price ?>
<?= $position->name ?>
<?= $position->quantity ?>
```

Comment: After click on button - redirect on 'cart-view', So, i think it's work! Thanks! But how can i do displaying cart items, i try ` foreach (Yii::$app->cart->getPositions() as $pos) {
            echo 'id: ' . $pos->getId() . ', cost: ' . $pos->getCost();
          }` but it isn't work

Comment: If your cart index view example is work, can i use it in all pages, right? I create _cart_item.php; I try put it(cart index view) in layout, but something gone wrong. It's display nothing. And when i try write "Yii::$app->ca" or "Yii::$app->cart->pos" my phpstorm don't show tips for autocomplete.

Comment: And it don't throw exception. So, i think trouble in adding items or in showing cart.. :(

Comment: Try it as controller view first. Its ok that phpstorm autocomplete not working with components. Try debug with print_r(Yii::$app->cart->positions)

Comment: result of `print_r(Yii::$app->cart->positions)`: `Array ( )`. One more thing: after click on button(add to cart) I getting redirect on `cart-view` and got #404 error. So, i can't create `actionCart-view()` right. I try `redirect(['cart'])` and create `actionCart` which render `cart-view` which render `_cart_item` and `print_r(Yii::$app->cart->positions)` anyway show empty array.

Comment: redirect on `cart-view` means you should have `actionCartView` in same controller. And check please first code example with form: `'action'=>Url::toRoute(['controllername/add-to-cart','id'=>$product->id])` Make sure you set `id` paramter with right value...

Comment: I solve troubles with views and controllers, it's ok. At `'id'=>$product->id` in my code is `'id'=>$model->id` so it's must set id correctly. I try iven `'id'=> 1` and `'id'=>1` anyway `print_r(Yii::$app->cart->positions)` show empty array.

Comment: if you get redirect, then form works properly. check `$cart` content after `$cart->put($model, 1);` before redirect

Comment: Looks like it transmitted in an array, but don't save.

Comment: Well it puts to cart, but can't store it in session. Check that session and cookies work properly. Also don't forget to setup in config/web.php `return [
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'fill in a secret key here',
        ],
    ],
];`

Comment: May be cookies disabled for your browser?

Comment: Nope, cookies is not disabled for my browser. And `cookieValidationKey` setted in config/main-local.php (i use advanced app). And in frontend/config/main.php i have `'session' => [
      'name' => 'FRONTENDID',
      'savePath' => __DIR__ . '/../tmp',
    ],` I did it for separate user session for frontend and backend

Comment: Without `cookieValidationKey` app is throw exception. And i think session works correctly, course i can successfully loging in at both part of app using diferent accounts

Comment: Sorry, but can't reproduce this error =\  and have no idea why it can't be stored in session then. I can only suggest to debug serializing and storing to session in vendor/omnilight.../ShopCart class.

Comment: Man! I solve problem. I used  `$cart = new ShoppingCart();` like wrote in official manual, and not noticed that at your it is `$cart = Yii::$app->cart;` Now it's work! Thanks for the spending time for me!